# Hadoop Custom InputFileFormat producing empty results

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, mapreduce

So I'm trying to import baseball event files from Retrosheet.org into Hadoop. Each game entry follows the following format, with each file containing a season's worth of game entries (this is an incomplete record just for example, some items removed for redundancy and to save space):

```
id,BOS192704230
version,1
info,inputprogvers,"version 7RS(19) of 07/07/92"
info,visteam,WS1
start,judgj101,"Joe Judge",0,5,3
start,myerb103,"Buddy Myer",0,6,6
start,blueo102,"Ossie Bluege",0,7,5
play,4,0,myerb103,??,,S/BG
play,4,0,blueo102,??,,CS2(2E4)
play,4,0,blueo102,??,,7/FL
play,4,0,ruelm101,??,,63
play,4,0,crowg102,??,,NP
sub,wests101,"Sam West",0,9,11
play,4,0,wests101,??,,K/C
play,4,1,wannp101,??,,NP
sub,liseh101,"Hod Lisenbee",0,9,1
play,4,1,wannp101,??,,W
play,4,1,rothj101,??,,CS2(26)
play,4,1,rothj101,??,,7/F
play,4,1,tobij101,??,,5/P
play,5,0,rices101,??,,6/P
data,er,crowg102,4
data,er,liseh101,0
data,er,braxg101,1
data,er,marbf101,0
data,er,harrs101,3
```

I'm making my first pass at importing this into Hadoop, and am having trouble implementing a proper custom InputFileFormat to successfully read such a record. I've been attempting to split the files on the first line of each game record (indicated by "id," followed by a team, season, date, and game code) using the regex "id,[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{9}". When I output this (I'm using a SequenceFile output, but both the SequenceFile and regular Text file outputs return the same result), I get an empty result file. Any point in the right direction would be extremely helpful. The code I've got so far is based on a template found here: http://dronamk.blogspot.com/2013/03/regex-custom-input-format-for-hadoop.html. I'm using essentially the same code posted there, just compiling the abovementioned regex instead of the included expression.

The class in question:

```
package project.baseball;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

public class RegexInputFormat extends
        InputFormat<LongWritable, TextArrayWritable> {

    public Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("id,[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{9}");
    private TextInputFormat textIF = new TextInputFormat();

    @Override
    public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        return textIF.getSplits(context);
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, TextArrayWritable> createRecordReader(
            InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        RegexRecordReader reader = new RegexRecordReader();

        if (pattern == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "No pattern specified - unable to create record reader");
        }

        reader.setPattern(pattern);
        return reader;
    }

    public static class RegexRecordReader extends
            RecordReader<LongWritable, TextArrayWritable> {

        private LineRecordReader lineRecordReader = new LineRecordReader();
        private Pattern pattern;
        TextArrayWritable value = new TextArrayWritable();

        public void setPattern(Pattern pattern2) {
            pattern = pattern2;
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            lineRecordReader.initialize(split, context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            while (lineRecordReader.nextKeyValue()) {
                Matcher matcher;

                matcher = pattern.matcher(lineRecordReader.getCurrentValue()
                        .toString());

                if (matcher.find()) {
                    int fieldCount;
                    Text[] fields;

                    fieldCount = matcher.groupCount();
                    fields = new Text[fieldCount];

                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
                        fields[i] = new Text(matcher.group(i + 1));
                    }

                    value.setFields(fields);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            return lineRecordReader.getCurrentKey();
        }

        @Override
        public TextArrayWritable getCurrentValue() throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return lineRecordReader.getProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            lineRecordReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex may miss the context ie what is around the line to split with.

Try this instead:

```
(.*)(id,([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{9}))(.*)
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. The pattern compiler is reading this as four groupings (one group for each of the parentheticals), so my output (an array of 4 Text objects) is one empty Text object, the full regex pattern match ("id,BOS192704260", for example), just the key ("BOS192704260"), and then another empty Text object. I'm thinking I need to adjust this to "(id,[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{9})" plus a longer pattern basically saying to take in everything until the initial pattern is found again?

Comment: @sitrick2 I would try this pattern: `(?s)(.*?)(id,[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{9})(.*?)`

Comment: It's still only returning the "id," + game key, with empty Text objects around either side. Would I have an easier time with this if I were looking for just the game key, and using "id," to indicate the end of the search?

Comment: still no go. Found a workaround. Hadoop really does not like multi-line records.